# Network Serial/COM Port

Tags: networking, serial

I need to connect to a single serial port over the network.  I was wondering if there was a hardware device that I could connect to the port and then install a virtual COM port on a Windows box.  The device would need some type of basic security - either IP filtering or authentication or both.  Otherwise, I just need a basic 9600 8-N-1 connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of Serial over Ethernet devices available, with wildly varying feature sets.

Just one example for a manufacturer: http://www.perle.com/products/Serial-to-Ethernet.shtml

Comment: That looks good.   They have a POE option and it is a little cheaper than the Digi.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with the [Digi](http://www.digi.com/products/serialservers/) Line of products. They have had decent security - at the very least user based authentication, and ssh access. I have to caveat this with i have never used there 1/2 port models just their higher end 16/32 port models so I can't speak directly to the capabilities of the smaller models.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple products that will allow you to connect to console ports via terminal emulators:

- [Avocent Cyclades](http://www.avocent.com/products/serial-consolemanagement.aspx)
- A low-end Cisco router (e.g. 2811 ISR) with an [async module](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps274/products_tech_note09186a00800a93f0.shtml)

Note that these products are mainly aimed at managing large numbers of devices; if you just need one connection, there may be other more cost effective alternatives.